# What algorithm can analyse dependencies with alternatives?

Tags: algorithm, dependencies, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a set of elements that have various dependencies on each other. These dependencies might be strict, eg. `a` depends on `b` and `c`; or some elements might have alternatives, eg. `s` depends on `t` or `u`. There are no circular dependencies.

I'm trying to do two things with the dependency information:

1. Determine whether a given set of elements has all dependencies resolved
2. List all possible completely resolved sets of elements

(In fact 2 is trivial given 1, since I can just generate all permutations and check them, where resources allow. There are probably better algorithms for that though.)

Are there algorithms for this that accommodate elements with alternative dependencies? I've found plenty that only account for strict dependencies, but I don't know enough terminology to narrow my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your elements are listed in **L**. Then, for each element **e** in **L** you validate that all *direct* dependencies are resolved. To validate each element **e**, you could walk through the list **D** of **e**'s dependencies and ensure that all elements **d** in **D** are found in **L**. To address the case of alternatives, now think of each **d** as a list of alternative dependencies on it's own.

```
for each d in e.D 
    d_ok = false
    for each alt_d in d
        if alt_d in L: d_ok = true, break
    if not d_ok: return false
return true
```

To list all possible sets that satisfy your dependencies, you can use a permutation index to iterate through all `alt_d`s in all possible different orders. You can generate these indices beforehand, because you know the number of alternatives for each element of **L**. You could check out `ndgrid` in MATLAB used as in the following code, assuming there is element **a** with three dependencies and **b** with two:

```
[idx_a, idx_b] = ndgrid(1:3, 1:2);
idx = [idx_a(:), idx_b(:)];
```

for a reference on how to use such precomputed indices, independently of the language you want to implement this in.

Comment: Ah good, this is what I'd started sketching out. Python's `any` and `all` functions will simplify this quite a bit too.

Comment: Okay, hope you see my edits. What I wrote initially was wrong. To clarify, do you consider a "root" in your set, i.e. is there one particular element whose dependencies must be resolved?

Comment: No, I could be validating any given set of elements to make sure that there are no elements with unresolved dependencies.

Comment: Okay, so then this would have to be applied for each element of **L**, but you won't have to use recursion. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

for non-strict dependencies, if it has only two choices,  eg. s depends on t or u(no more), you can regard it as [2SAT-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2SAT) and solve it.

Comment: I can't guarantee there would only be two dependencies. Although theoretically, a set of more than two dependencies could be transformed into nested sets of two (I think).